# Redirecting after the completion of a backend function with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

recently I've been dabbling with express web servers to build a website that can be signed into with Discord's OAuth2 API. I've been using the npm module express-session to store sensitive information within the session for security purposes but am having trouble when it comes to redirecting after doing so. The problem I am having is that the code will complete and the redirect request will even be made (I can see the GET request be logged), but the client web browser does not move. Hopefully somebody will be able to help me out as to why, I believe it may be related to the redirect request not making it to the client but I'm not entirely sure how I would get it to the client. I have included the relevant routes below.

```
router.get('/callback', function(req,res) {
    logDate(req)
    res.render('callback')
});

router.post('/callback', bodyParser.json(), function(req,res) {
    logDate(req)
    ssn = req.session
    var originalUrl = req.body.location
    token = originalUrl.substring(originalUrl.indexOf("&") + 1);
    token = token.substring(0, token.indexOf('&'));
    token = token.replace('access_token=','');
    ssn.token = token
    res.redirect('/login');
});

router.get('/login', function(req,res) {
    logDate(req)
    ssn = req.session
    var ssnToken = `Bearer ${ssn.token}`
    function login(data, callback) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ssnToken
        axios.get('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me')
            .then(response => {
                ssn.login = "true"
                ssn.username = response.data.username
                ssn.discriminator = response.data.discriminator
                ssn.userid = response.data.id
                if (response.data.avatar) {
                    ssn.avatar = response.data.avatar
                    if (response.data.avatar.startsWith("a_")) {
                        ssn.pfp = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${ssn.userid}/${ssn.avatar}.gif`
                    }
                    else {
                        ssn.pfp = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${ssn.userid}/${ssn.avatar}.png`
                    }
                }
                else {
                    ssn.pfp = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/${ssn.discriminator % 5}.png`
                } 
                callback(data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    login("hhhh", (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        console.log(ssn.login)
        console.log(ssn.username)
        console.log(ssn.discriminator)
        console.log(ssn.userid)
        if (ssn.avatar) {
            console.log(ssn.avatar)
        }
        console.log(ssn.pfp)
        res.redirect(‘/dashboard’)
        
    });
});
```

By the way, the POST request is sent to /callback when 'callback' is rendered. It is send via an XMLHttpRequest by the client. The redirect I am referring to is the last one shown in the code block. Thank you for taking the time to read my first question.

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 0):

In `EcmaScript 6` you can use the [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keywords. So instead of using callbacks it easier to just transform your code into `async / await` form just like this:

```
router.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
    logDate(req)
    ssn = req.session
    var ssnToken = `Bearer ${ssn.token}`

    try {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ssnToken
        const response = await axios.get('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me')
        
        ssn.login = "true"
        ssn.username = response.data.username
        ssn.discriminator = response.data.discriminator
        ssn.userid = response.data.id
        
        if (response.data.avatar) {
            ssn.avatar = response.data.avatar
            if (response.data.avatar.startsWith("a_")) {
                ssn.pfp = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${ssn.userid}/${ssn.avatar}.gif`
            } else {
                ssn.pfp = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${ssn.userid}/${ssn.avatar}.png`
            }
        } else {
            ssn.pfp = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/${ssn.discriminator % 5}.png`
        } 
    } catch(ex) {
        console.error('axios request ex:', ex)
    }
    
    console.log(result)
    console.log(ssn.login)
    console.log(ssn.username)
    console.log(ssn.discriminator)
    console.log(ssn.userid)
    
    if (ssn.avatar) {
        console.log(ssn.avatar)
    }
    
    console.log(ssn.pfp)
    res.redirect(‘/dashboard’)
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, even with your code, the page refuses to redirect, it simply stops moving in the same place as it did before.

Comment: Is there any exception thrown ?

Comment: No, in fact, it looks as if the request is successful in that I see the GET request logged in the console of the Express app. I remember reading something about it being possible for the request to be sent to the backend rather than the client? I wonder if something like that could be going on?

Comment: I would try something like: `res.json({data: ssn.pfp})` instead of `res.redirect('/dashboard')`, just to make sure the login was succeessful.